SQL/Laravel: Get parents in tree data structure
Hello everyone) I use Laravel, MariaDB.
For example, we have a table like this, let's say categories.



id
name
_lft
_rgt
parent_id
path
is_folder




1373
Windows
1
10
NULL
1373
1


1374
Glass unit
2
7
1373
1373.1374
1


1375
Accessories
8
9
1373
1373.1375
1


1376
Installation
3
4
1374
1373.1374.1376
0


1377
Adjustment
5
6
1374
1373.1374.1377
0



The Categories model uses the Kalnoy\Nestedset\NodeTrait trait.
In the code below, the query builder already contains basic filters (for example, by name)
if (!empty($filters['recursiveSearch']) && CommonService::parseBoolean($filters['recursiveSearch']) === true) {
/** @var QueryBuilder $query */
}

When passing the recursiveSearch parameter, it is necessary to output not only the values ​​that match the filter, but also all their parents.
For example: by the filter name=adjust we get the string Adjustment. with recursiveSearch you also need to get Windows and Glass unit.

The query can also have a filter parentId. If parentId=null&name=adjust&recursiveSearch=true then it should return Windows
Please help :)
Initially I thought to do just with('ancestors'), but the result gets into the relations, and should be in the main query.
Then I made an additional query, got the result of the first selection, got pluck('ancestors') and already substituted their IDs into the resulting query. It worked, but if in the initial selection there are, for example, 1000 records and each has 3 parents, then in the end there will be where on 3000 IDs.

You could use a recursive CTE query.

As an idea, without consider Laravel, you can do this without recursion, since you have the full path for each row.



id
name
_lft
_rgt
parent_id
path
is_folder




1373
Windows    1
10
null
1373

1


1374
Glass unit
2
7
1373
1373.1374
1


1375
Accessories
8
9
1373
1373.1375
1


1376
Installation
3
4
1374
1373.1374.1376
0


1377
Adjustment
5
6
1374
1373.1374.1377
0



select p.*
from categories c
inner join categories p on
    find_in_set(cast(p.id as char),replace(c.path,'.',','))>0
where c.id=1377




id
name
_lft
_rgt
parent_id
path
is_folder




1373
Windows    1
10
null
1373

1


1374
Glass unit
2
7
1373
1373.1374
1


1377
Adjustment
5
6
1374
1373.1374.1377
0



fiddle
Simpler do this by 2 queries

Take path for desired id

select path from categories where id=1377

Output is '1373.1374.1377'.
2.Query all parents with parameter '1373,1374,1377'
select *
from categories
where  find_in_set(cast(id as char),'1373,1374,1377')>0

Request for id and all childrens
select *
from categories c
where  find_in_set(cast(1374 as char),replace(c.path,'.',','))>0




id
name
_lft
_rgt
parent_id
path
is_folder




1374
Glass unit
2
7
1373
1373.1374
1


1376
Installation
3
4
1374
1373.1374.1376
0


1377
Adjustment
5
6
1374
1373.1374.1377
0



fiddle

$query->join('categories as p', function ($join) {
    $join->on(DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET(CAST(p.id AS CHAR) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, REPLACE(categories.path COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, '.', ','))"), '>', DB::raw('0'));
})
    ->addSelect('p.*')
    ->distinct();

This worked in laravel.
